# Using a comparison test to solve an improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

In this problem above, I get different answers based on what function I use for the comparison test. I was wondering how I know which one is correct and why.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please don't post question details as images.

Comment: Please read again the comparison test from your book or notes or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test#For_integrals). It can only work one way at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison tests say that $ \int_a^\infty f(x) \ dx $ converges if $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\int (a,\infty)$ and $ \int_a^\infty g(x) \ dx $ converges and diverges if $f(x)\ge h(x)$ for all $x\int(a,\infty)$ and $\int_a^\infty h(x)\ dx$ diverges.

but if $f(x) < h(x)$ and $\int_a^{\infty} h(x)\ dx$ diverges then you have not proven anything.

So, in the linked example, the logic shown in green is correct reasoning, and what is in pink is not.